# Pybrain reinforcement learning; dimension of state

Tags: python, neural-network, pybrain, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I am working on a project to combine reinforcement learning with traffic light simulations using the package Pybrain. I have read the tutorial and implemented my own subclasses of `Environment` and `Task`. I am using an `ActionValueNetwork` as controller because I want my state to be a vector with continuous values such that it can contain information about for example the number of cars waiting on each lane, the total waiting times per lane and more.

I set the input dimensions of the `ActionValueNetwork` to the dimensions of my state vector, which would suggest that it's possible to use vectors as state variables. When I use the Q-learner or the SARSA learner the code runs fine at first but I obtain an error message as soon as the method `learn()` is called. This function contains the line

```
state = int(state)
```

and the error message is

```
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

which would suggest that only scalar shaped states can be used.

Does the pybrain reinforcement learning environment support vector shaped states? If so, how can I modify my code such that it will work with their implementations of Q-learning or other methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found my problem in the meantime. I was using the `Q()` learner but should have used the `NFQ()` learner which implements the [neural-fitted Q-learning algorithm](http://ml.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/_media/publications/rieecml05.pdf). Now it works.